# Intensionally delay data synchronisation for subscribed collection

Tags: meteor

Meteor app, typical pattern, I have publish on a server, subscribe on a client.

Reactivity is great, but now I have a need to let client synchronize its local minimongo (or, lets say, fetch new values from server) **only** each, lets say, 30 seconds.

Is there a way to do so? In other words I must be able to delay synchronisation for **n** seconds and repeat it every **n** seconds also.

The only pattern comes in mind right now is a very dirty one - just use an another helper for layout that only updates each *n* seconds, but that doesn't save me traffic because synchronisation will happen anyway, I will only visually make it like its been synchronized not in real time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Well, Imagine having meteor's microscope posts being upvoted by 10k users - posts will **crawl** each second. I do not want that in real time, I want it with delay.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tested and confirmed? Because I don't think that's true.

Comment: yes, I am sure. By crawl I mean (assuming you have upvote and downvote) each post will jump each second, and it will be a mess for your eyes.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant crawl in the usual sense (slow down). That does sound more like a UI issue, though.

Comment: ah, sorry for using the wrong word them, I wasn't sure which one to use. Yes, the problem is that I do not want posts data to be synced in real time for posts not to jump up and down each moment someone upvote/downvote it.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but maybe you can do something with subscribe and unsubscribe and turn it back on in 30 seconds. I think you will need the [iron router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) for this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't necessarily want to prevent the subscription itself from stopping/starting (this would get difficult as meteor will think there is no data and will remove everything reactively).

Really you just want to prevent the UI from updating as often. One way to do that is the following, which will change the local cursor query to be temporarily reactive (allowing the DOM to update) every 5 seconds, and then non-reactive right away:

```
# client.coffee

Meteor.setInterval ->
  Session.set('reactive', true)
  Session.set('reactive', false)
, 5000

Template.test.helpers
  docs: -> Collection.find {}, {reactive:Session.get('reactive')}
```

This would be my initial approach just to demo the concept, and it seems pretty hacky; it works in a tiny app but I haven't tested it in anything big. I've never seen this kind of thing being used in a real app, but understand why you might want it.

Comment: This seems to be the variant that I mentioned as dirty-one, but at least it's a solution, not perfect tho.

Comment: This approach works better that other suggestions, and so far I haven't got any major issues, so I am marking it as acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to add a `updateTimestamp` to each document. Then you can publish all the documents until a specific time-stamp and update this every 30 seconds. Making sure you do not get the documents every time they are added or changed

the biggest difficulty would be to manage the time difference between the client and the server.

```
Meteor.publish("allPosts", function(until){
    return Posts.find({updateTimeStamp: {$lte: until}});
});
```

and on the client

```
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe("allPosts", new Date());
}, 30000)
```